# Elasticsearch searching on two index which is having one to many relationships

Tags: java, sql, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Am indexing oracle table in elasticsearch using logstash. But here i have one requirement that have 1 to many relationships with another table. for example,

Product Table

```
id          code
1001        AB-1234-01-T
1002        AB-5678-01-T
1003        CD-1234-02-T
1004        EF-1234-03-T
1005        AB-1234-02-T
1006        XY-1234-02-T
```

Link Table

```
Prod_id     Link_id     Type
1002        1003        Reg
1002        1004        Reg
1002        1005        Reg
1002        1001        Reg
1002        1006        Reg
1007        1008        AVL
```

If am searching for code `AB-5678-01-T` in `product` table.

```
Step 1 :  it should take `id` for the code `AB-5678-01-T` from `product` table.
Step 2 :  it should check `prod_id`  field in `Link` table where the `id` (product table) is available or not and the `type` should be `Reg`.
Step 3 :  If the `prod_id` available of `type` `Reg`, take all the `Link_id` from the `Link` table.
Step 4 :  it should check in `id` field of `product` table and return the corresponding `code` as a result
```

it should return the below results.

Results

```
CD-1234-02-T
EF-1234-03-T
AB-1234-02-T
AB-1234-01-T
XY-1234-02-T
```

Any idea from anyone, how can we achieve this requirement in elasticsearch, do we need to create two index for each table and do the searching or anyother way is there.?

Comment: why do you want two indexes? why cant you have one index with all the infor required - as one document; makes things less complicated.

Comment: Do you have any idea., how to bring it as one index..?

Comment: via logstash. Write a query to select all. something like `select * from Product inner join Link ON Product.id = Link.id`. This will generate a event with all the field and use aggregation to add to elastic via logstash

Comment: do you have any sample for `aggregation `

Comment: Elastic has a good documentation for [Aggregate Filter Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html)

Comment: Also, if you can combine all of the rows into one row for an ID comma separated, then you dont even need aggregation. something like `1002 |  AB-5678-01-T | 1003,1004,.. | Reg` - this would be one document that will be added into elastic and easy to search.